# Ionic app run on device Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

[image: Errors]

I can run ionic serve without error. I also installed cordova whitelist plugin and solve the CORS problems from api side.

[image]

I also followed this tutorial [Handling CORS issues with Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/). I don't know why if there is still any errors. I can run the app on ionic serve and ionic serve -v but not ionic run. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This screenshot is from a device? In that case, you cant have the server in the localhost, because this refers to the device himself, you have to point to the IP of the server

Comment: This is screenshot from live debug tool from Chrome. I also point it to the server IP as you see in the screenshot cors test below. Do you have any other idea why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is caused by whitelist.

You should use [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) if its not included in your cordova project

Also you should add this to your config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

And also add this meta to your index.html, or main page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

This is wildcard, in production you should be more restrictive.

Comment: Sadly that I have used it but the problem still exists >.<. Here is my wildcard: 


`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' http://s.sachmem.com/ ; connect-src *; frame-src *; media-src *">`

Comment: Please tell me how did  you solved this issue.. Iam stuck from  last 3 days